# How do i click button from keypress event

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to click a button when i press F1

this is my code

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
            {
                buttonGfxIn_Click.PerformClick();
            }

        }
```

But i get this error

that button name Is a 'method' which is not valid in the given context error

Comment: You probably need `buttonGfxIn.PerformClick()`. The `buttonGfxIn_Click()` is a method for handling the clicks rather than the button itself.

Comment: `buttonGfxIn.PerformClick();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have test with a example and it is working well. try it.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("button1 was clicked");
        }

        protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)

        {
            KeyEventArgs e = new KeyEventArgs(keyData);
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)

            {
                button1_Click("", e);
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

        }
    }
```